# store itdr on x64

Tags: c, assembly, windows-7, device-driver

I tried to get idt address in my driver, I made function in asm which returns what idtr contains:

```
.data
  myData dq 0

.code
Function PROC
  sidt myData
  mov rax, myData
  ret
Function ENDP
END
```

But the address which I get is weird, for example in windbg:

```
r idtr
idtr=fffff80000b95080
```

However my driver shows:

```
idtr = f80000b950800fff
```

I read that on x64 IDTR contains 64-bit base address of IDT table. I would appreciate if anyone explain why my output is not the same as from WinDbg.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what the Intel docs say about the SIDT instruction:

> In 64-bit mode, the operand size is fixed at 8+2 bytes. The instruction stores 8-byte base and 2-byte limit values.

and:

```
DEST[0:15] <- IDTR(Limit);
DEST[16:79] <- IDTR(Base);
```

This means your `myData` variable needs to be 10 bytes long, and the instructions stores the limit in the first 2 bytes and base address in the next 8 bytes. This also explains why your value matches with WinDbg's value after the first `ffff` bytes.

Comment: So I should not return this value, but pass appropriate structure to this function and correctly fill with limit and Base? 
Thanks for answer.

Comment: @Vasilij: Yes, you can pass the address of a structure that contains 10 bytes (2+8) and `SIDT` will fill in the values correctly.